# Details view C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, detailsview

Virtually everything i have googled describes the above perfectly in master/details view on one form. Is there anyway to do this on two forms? Basically what i want to achieve is to have my Main Form display a datagridview (with binding source, tableadapter etc) and be able to double click a record in the datagridview and have it open a new form with a details view bound to the record that was selected on the main form datagridview.

I've seen a few pseudo code examples on how to do this but would greatly appreciate a link or C# code on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to extract the selected value and have to give it to your new Form (for example in it's constructor) - the rest should be straight forward and the same as in master/detail on one form

Comment: @Temrus - This isn't the place to come to get someone else to do the work that you think it too difficult.

Comment: How to bind Bindong Source from EditForm to Binding Source on the Main form?

Comment: no you pass the id (or whatever) of the Master to the Details form and there generate a new Source with only the detail-data beloning to this master-id.

Comment: what's the problem? Shall we go writing you code without you showing us what you did to this point? Would that help you? Maybe we can get to the point where we can start a project, post 5 lines into SO and at the end of the day we can show our bosses "the code" ... till then you will have to give details before you can get more

Comment: CKoenig, are you in a bad mood? Dont answer on my post pls if you DONT WANT TO ANSWER accurately...

Comment: no I'm in no bad mood and I answer a comment to my answer. And as you see I'm the only one answering at all - why do you think this is so? You may also consider the comment Lazarus gave ... and shouting will bring you nowwhere - if you are not willing to give any more infos on your problem then please close this

Comment: How to bind Binding Source from EditForm to Binding Source on the Main form?

Comment: ok - short answer: not at all. Long one: you could do this be passing the binding-source of your Main form to your EditForm and binding it there just like in the case of your two Views on one Form, but I would not do this at all but - as I said - but load the detail-data for the master-id and give this master-id to your EditForm. This is way more flexible and better design. If you decide to change your Binding of your main-form you won't have to change your Edit-form as well, ...